# How to Stream sort a list in that case?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of objects in Java with two timeStamp, like :

Obj (TimeStamp ts, TimeStamp generationTs, int value).

At the end, I don't want two items in the list with the same ts. If there are, I want to keep only the one with the most recent generationTs.

Actually, I have that code, it works, but I'd like to know if with streams, I can't do something better ?

```
list.sort(Collections.reverseOrder());
List<Obj> returnedList = Lists.newArrayList();
if (!list.isEmpty()) {
   returnedList.add(list.get(0));
   Iterator<Obj> i = list.iterator();
   while (i.hasNext()) {
       Obj lastObj = returnedList.get(returnedList.size() - 1);
       Obj nextObj = i.next();
       if (!lastObj.getTs().isEqual(nextObj.getTs())) {
           returnedList.add(nextObj);
       } else {
           if (lastObj.getGenerationTs().isBefore(nextObj.getGenerationTs())) {
             returnedList.remove(lastObj);
             returnedList.add(nextObj);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

If the list is :

```
{("2019-05-02T09:00:00Z", "2019-05-02T21:00:00Z", 1),
("2019-05-02T09:30:00Z", "2019-05-02T21:00:00Z", 2),
("2019-05-02T10:00:00Z", "2019-05-02T21:00:00Z", 3),
("2019-05-02T10:30:00Z", "2019-05-02T21:00:00Z", 4),
("2019-05-02T09:30:00Z", "2019-05-02T22:00:00Z", 5),
("2019-05-02T10:00:00Z", "2019-05-02T22:00:00Z", 6) }
```

It must returns :

```
{("2019-05-02T09:00:00Z", "2019-05-02T21:00:00Z", 1),
("2019-05-02T09:30:00Z", "2019-05-02T22:00:00Z", 5),
("2019-05-02T10:00:00Z", "2019-05-02T22:00:00Z", 6) 
("2019-05-02T10:30:00Z", "2019-05-02T21:00:00Z", 4) }
```

Comment: Try looking for `List.removeIf`, but you need to make sure that you don't remove element for its own existence.

Comment: @Naman : removeIf() works when you have a predicate you know.. In my case, I want to remove element x if : ` list(x).getTs()= = list(y).getTs() && list(x).getGenerationTs().isBefore(list(y).getGenerationTs()) `

Comment: I would though prefer not to go via the stream route here. Yet one possible way is to collect toMap, with `timestamp` as the key and `Obj` as a value and then in the `mergeFunction` ensure you fulfill your `generatedTs` condition. Finally get the values of this map that you would be interested in.

Comment: `Better` can be very subjective.  If this is purely academic, fine.  But if your code works, don't "fix" it.

Comment: just wondering: you are not doing anything that could be better done using SQL, right?

Comment: @WJS I agree, but it's absolutely not academic. It's simply about performances ! I thought that with stream I would get a faster execution. And I don't think the actual solution is the better.. But if the better way isn't with stream, I won't use it ! Maybe my question was not rightly asked...

Comment: @Roland data comes from CassandraDB, and cql is not as permissive as sql ..

Comment: @yahal Nothing wrong with your question.  But most of the time, off the cuff code optimizations don't really improve much or improve what needs to be improved.  If one is really concerned, after its done, run a profiler on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly do it using `Stream` using a map collector and then getting the values

```
Collection<Obj> objects = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Obj::getTimeStamp,
                              Function.identity(),
                              (o1, o2) -> o1.getGenerationTs().isBefore(o2.getGenerationTs()) ? o2 : o1))
    .values();

List<Obj> listOfObjects = new ArrayList<>(objects);
```

Or even shorter:

```
List<Obj> result = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.toMap(Obj::getTimeStamp,
                        Function.identity(),
                        (o1, o2) -> o1.getGenerationTs().isBefore(o2.getGenerationTs()) ? o2 : o1),
                m -> new ArrayList<>(m.values())));
```

Comment: might want to wrap the output of stream pipeline around with `new ArrayList<>()`

Comment: Can do this right in the collector: `List<Obj> result = list.stream().collect( Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toMap(…), m -> new ArrayList<>(m.values()));`

Comment: that solution is almost like what I was begining to get, in better, thanks ! I only added `.sorted(Comparator.comparing(LoadCurvePointBO::getTs)) ` to sort it by ts asc

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this:

```java
Map<TimeStamp, Optional<Obj>> result = 
         list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                                Obj::getTs,
                                Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Obj::getGenerationTs))
         ));
```

More complete options as @Naman stated in comment:

```java
list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                       Obj::getTs,
                       Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Obj::getGenerationTs))
              )).values().stream()
                .filter(Optional::isPresent) 
                .map(Optional::get)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: What OP might be looking for could be something like `return list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Obj::getTs,
                        Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Obj::getGeneratedTs))
                )).values()
                .stream()
                .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                .map(Optional::get)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 0):

Below is one way of doing it.

Grouping one the first timestamp and then using maxBy to find the object with the latest generation timestamp. Finally sort on the first timestamp and print it out.

The fact that maxBy will produce an Optional is a bit ugly, but I couldn't find a way to avoid it.

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.maxBy;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class SortTest {

@Test
public void t() {
    final Stream<Obj> s = Stream.of(new Obj("2019-05-02T09:00:00Z", "2019-05-02T21:00:00Z", 1),
            new Obj("2019-05-02T09:30:00Z", "2019-05-02T21:00:00Z", 2),
            new Obj("2019-05-02T10:00:00Z", "2019-05-02T21:00:00Z", 3),
            new Obj("2019-05-02T10:30:00Z", "2019-05-02T21:00:00Z", 4),
            new Obj("2019-05-02T09:30:00Z", "2019-05-02T22:00:00Z", 5),
            new Obj("2019-05-02T10:00:00Z", "2019-05-02T22:00:00Z", 6));

    s.collect(groupingBy(o -> o.ts, maxBy((o1, o2) -> o1.generationTs.compareTo(o2.generationTs))))
    .values()
    .stream()
    .map(Optional::get)
    .sorted((o1, o2) -> o1.ts.compareTo(o2.ts))
    .forEach(System.out::println);

}

private class Obj {
    Instant ts;
    Instant generationTs;
    int i;

    Obj(final String ts, final String generationTs, final int i) {
        this.ts = Instant.parse(ts);
        this.generationTs = Instant.parse(generationTs);
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s %s %d", ts, generationTs, i);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a sorted list (descending by `generationTs`), like you have in your example code, you can use a `HashSet` and `Collection.removeIf()` to remove all duplicate timestamps from that list:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Obj::getTs)
        .thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(Obj::getGenerationTs)
                .reversed()));

Set<Timestamp> keys = new HashSet<>();
list.removeIf(o -> !keys.add(o.getTs()));
```

With this solution you don't have to create a new list, you just modify the list you have. The set stores all keys you want to maintain in the list. Because the list is sorted the newest objects are retained in the list, while the other values are removed.

The result with the data you shared will be:

```
Obj[ts=2019-05-02T09:00:00Z, generationTs=2019-05-02T21:00:00Z, value=1]
Obj[ts=2019-05-02T09:30:00Z, generationTs=2019-05-02T22:00:00Z, value=5]
Obj[ts=2019-05-02T10:00:00Z, generationTs=2019-05-02T22:00:00Z, value=6]
Obj[ts=2019-05-02T10:30:00Z, generationTs=2019-05-02T21:00:00Z, value=4]
```

If you already have a sorted list, this solution should be one of the fastest.